# Frequent itemset SQL

Tags: sql, frequency

I'm using SAS for a piece of coursework. At the moment, I have a set of Order IDs and Product IDs. I want to found out which products are most frequently ordered together. Think, milk and cereal in a grocery basket.

I am not very good at programming, so would really appreciate if anyone could spare a bit of time and write a simple few lines of SQL I can easily use. Its not a heavy dataset and there are only two columns (Order_ID and Product_ID)

For example:

**Order ID**  Product ID

**10001**   64564564

**10001**   546456

**10001**   54646

**10003**   5464

**10003**   342346

I've spent three hours researching now and am a bit desperate :(

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Hi I'm not sure what is DBMS, but I am working on SAS which is based on proc-sql

Answer (score 1):

If you think about it, you can find the answer by asking the question this way: for every possible pair of products, how many times did the two products occur on the same order.  Then order by the count to float the answer(s) to the top:

```
select 
    p1.product_id, p2.product_id, count(*) times_order_together 
from
    orders p1
    inner join
    orders p2
    on
        p1.order_id = p2.order_id
        and
        p1.product_id != p2.product_id 
group by
    p1.product_id, p2.product_id
order by
    count(*) desc
```

Products that weren't ever ordered together don't show up at all.  Also - pairs are represented twice - a row for eggs with milk and a row for milk with eggs.  These duplicate pairs are removable - but it gets uglier - and simple is good.

To elaborate a bit, `p1` and `p2` are aliases of orders.  You do that to be able to use a data source more than once - and yet distinguish between them.  Also, the `count(*) times_order_together` is just giving the name 'times_order_together' to the calculation `count(*)`.  It's counting the number of times a product pairing occurs in an order.

Comment: thanks! However I don't understand how I can select   p1.product_id, p2.product_id if its only from one column? Sorry if this is a stupid question

Comment: The trick is to select from the table twice and join the two selections together. You never did tell us the name of the table - In my example, I'm guessing/assuming the table is called 'orders'.  This technique is called a same-table join and is pretty common when using sql-based systems.

Answer (score 0):

how about something like:

```
create table order_together (order_id, product_id1, product_id2);

insert into order_together
(order_id, product_id1, product_id2)
select o1.order_id, o1.product_id, o2.product_id
from order_line o1, order_line o2
where o1.order_id = o2.order_id 

/* you dont want them equal and you also dont
want to insert cereal-milk and milk-cereal on the same order*/
and o1.product_id < o2.product_id
```

now you have pairs of products together and you can go wild with counts and stats.  Mind you, this is quite naive and would blow up in volume quite quickly.

Maybe

```
select count(distinct order_id), o1.product_id, o2.product_id 
... 
group by o1.product_id, o2.product_id
```

would be better.

*in response to be comment*

but you are grabbing pairs of ordered together products, coming from different rows of the same order's order_lines.

Try this on sqlfiddle.com

put this in left, build schema pane.  it creates the tables.

```
create table order_line(order_no int, product_id varchar(10));

create table order_together(order_no int, product_id1 varchar(10), product_id2 varchar(10));
```

put this in right pane, Run SQL

```
insert into order_line(order_no, product_id) values(1, 'milk');
insert into order_line(order_no, product_id) values (1, 'cereal');
insert into order_line(order_no, product_id) values (1, 'rice');
insert into order_line(order_no, product_id) values (2, 'milk');
insert into order_line(order_no, product_id) values (2, 'cereal');

insert into order_line(order_no, product_id) values (3, 'milk');
insert into order_line(order_no, product_id) values (3, 'cookies');
insert into order_line(order_no, product_id) values(4, 'milk');
insert into order_line(order_no, product_id) values (4, 'cookies');
insert into order_line(order_no, product_id) values(5, 'rice');
insert into order_line(order_no, product_id) values (5, 'icecream');

select o1.order_no, o1.product_id as product_from_row1, o2.product_id as product_from_row2
from order_line o1, order_line o2
where o1.order_no = o2.order_no
and o1.product_id < o2.product_id
```

gives:

```
order_no    product_from_row1   product_from_row2
1   milk    rice
1   cereal  milk
1   cereal  rice
2   cereal  milk
3   cookies     milk
4   cookies     milk
5   icecream    rice
```

give it a try, then think about what the query is requesting, which is joining different order_lines of the **same** order.  That's pretty much the definition of "ordered together".

Comment: Hey @jl-peyret! Thanks for reply, but I'm not sure if (order_id, product_id1, product_id2) would work? My data is in two columns, with order_id and product_id respectively. For example, column one is made of all the order ids, and column two is all the product ids that correspond to the order id. I have edited my question to attempt to illustrate this!